# How to update the Proxy for WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I want to insert the record into table using Service.I had one Service already and i written new function and implemented in service but not able to get it into my web application.In short i want to get the latest function written in service to be in my web application.
[image]

It is one of Project under my web application that refers to service.
[image]

and this is my Service project and I have written one new function as follows

```
 public void InsertVISDetails(VISInfo visInfo)
        {
            try {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)) {
                                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                    cmd.CommandText = "usp_Insert_VISDimention_userActivity";
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page",visInfo.Page);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginDate",visInfo.LoginDate);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ElapsedTime",visInfo.ElapsedTime);
                                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                                    conn.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                } catch (Exception) {
            }    
        }
```

This new function I want to invoke in my web application

Comment: Did you update your service reference by right clicking on it? Isn't it updated even you do that?

Comment: Yes..I tried but no updates..

Comment: Did you add the new operation to your service interface as well?

Comment: Yes..
public interface ILogService {
        [OperationContract]
        void InsertVISDetails(VISInfo visInfo);
    }

Comment: Have you updated the service reference? Right click the service reference and select the 'Update sevice reference' option

Comment: @SantyEssac From Visual Studio, It is better to remove the reference completely and try adding it again. That works most of the time.

Comment: To add it my Service must be hosted/running right?